# Minimizing the maximum of (A[i]*B[i])

Tags: arrays, optimization, max, minimum

Given an array A of size n and number x create another array of size n, Lets call it B, such that B[i] >=0 (n>i>=0) and sigma ( B[i] for all valid i ) is equal to x in such a way that max(A[0]*B[0], , , A[n-1]*B[n-1) can be minimized.

provided that:

A[i] >0 for each valid i

x>0

sample example:

> A={1,4,3},
>
> x=5

then B should be

> B={4,0,1}

and minimum value

> => max(1*4,4*0,3*1) => 4

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow?  Can you state your question more clearly?  Also, can you please touch up the grammar, syntax, and punctuation?

Comment: Does this belong to stats.stackexchange.com?

Comment: is x the sum of B values?

Comment: Yes, but i solved the problem later on. Thank You for your time.